# How to handle questions that will never get an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Consider for example [ZFS on Linux gets corrupted on export](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70683/2465). This is not a duplicate of meta [What do we do about abandoned questions, with a correct answer never accepted?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/888/2465), because this is about questions without a correct answer.

A valid question is initially asked (this particular one has even been protected), possibly one or more answers are provided, but no answer that solves the OP's problem. Eventually, the OP says that for one reason or another, the issue is no longer relevant and possibly the opportunity for determining the correctness of an answer no longer exists. Also, the OP has not provided a self-answer (such as is the case in the cited example), or if there exists a self-answer, it does not actually answer the question.

Hence, the question will likely never receive an accepted answer, the incentive to answer at all is low, and the existing answers may provide little or no value to the community.

**At that point, how should we handle the question?**

Answer (score 4):

For this specific question: it is not THAT old, so just leave it alone. This is IMHO also the general approach to this "problem".

There are questions with no valid answer up until now. Sometimes other people will adopt such a answer and start a bounty for it (I once earned one for one of these) and I already did this myself (start a bounty on a question I did not ask).

Sometimes Community♦ will bump the post to on front page (I stumbled across a question from 2011 on SF just a few minutes ago that way).

And sometimes some users start going through the unanswered questions...

So even if the OP has no interest in such a question (any more) you can still earn points for good answers.

Comment: I find it ironic that OP hasn't accepted this answer.

Comment: @strugee - as do I.